# Binding a Long/Int64 field to NumericUpdown leads to OleDbException "Too few parameters" on update

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I am stuck with this problem the whole day, so maybe someone has a tip for me.

The environment: MS Access DB, VB.NET, OleDb-Driver, MS Access Database Engine 2016.

I am trying to bind a Long/Int64 field to a NumericUpDown control, but on update I get always the OleDbException "Too few parameters". I am pretty sure that the long field is the problem, because when I delete it from the table (and comment out the code for it) everything works fine. I am not sure that a NumericUpDown is suitable for this task, but it's underlying datatype is decimal and decimal has way more space as a long needs. So here is some code:

In the DataLayer:

```
Private Sub InitializeDataSet()
    Dim LocFields = String.Join("], [", Fields)
    Dim SQL As String = "SELECT [" & LocFields & "] FROM [" & Table & "]"

    DAMain = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, Connection)
    Using Builder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(DAMain) With {
            .ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges
        }
        Builder.GetInsertCommand()
        Builder.GetUpdateCommand()
        Builder.GetDeleteCommand()
    End Using

    DS = New DataSet
    DAMain.Fill(DS, Table)
End Sub

Public Sub Update()
    DAMain.Update(DS, Table)  ' <-- Here the exception happens
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property DataSource As Object
    Get
        Return DS
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property DataMember As String
    Get
        Return Table
    End Get
End Property
```

We are here in a class, so the variables are:
Table = the name of the table
Fields = the list of the fields in the table
Connection = the OleDbConnection
DAMain = the OleDbDataAdapter
DS = the DataSet

In the Form:

```
Private DL As OleDbDataLayer
Private WithEvents BSource As New BindingSource

Public Sub New(DataLayer As OleDbDataLayer)
    InitializeComponent()

    DL = DataLayer

    BSource.DataSource = DL.DataSource
    BSource.DataMember = DL.DataMember
    BSource.AllowNew = True
    BSource.Sort = DL.OrderBy
    BSource.Position = 0

    InitializeFields()
End Sub

Private Sub DataUpdate()
    BSource.EndEdit()
    DL.Update()
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeFields()
    NUD.Minimum = Long.MinValue
    NUD.Maximum = Long.MaxValue

    Dim Binding As New Binding("Value", BSource, "F_Long")
    AddHandler Binding.Format, AddressOf FormatDBNull
    AddHandler Binding.Parse, AddressOf ParseNumericUpDown
    NUD.DataBindings.Add(Binding)
End Sub

Private Sub FormatDBNull(sender As Object, e As ConvertEventArgs)
    If Convert.IsDBNull(e.Value) Then
        Select Case e.DesiredType
            Case = GetType(Decimal) : e.Value = 0
            Case = GetType(Date) : e.Value = Today
            Case = GetType(Boolean) : e.Value = False
            Case Else
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ParseNumericUpDown(sender As Object, e As ConvertEventArgs)
    Select Case e.DesiredType
        Case = GetType(Byte)
            e.Value = Convert.ToByte(e.Value)
        Case = GetType(Short)
            e.Value = Convert.ToInt16(e.Value)
        Case = GetType(Integer)
            e.Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.Value)
        Case = GetType(Long)
            e.Value = Convert.ToInt64(e.Value)
        Case Else
            ' Do Nothing
    End Select
End Sub
```

Here NUD is the NumericUpDown control which should be obvious.

Maybe I should use another control type? TextBox? MaskedTextBox?

Comment: Are you sure that DS and Table are not null when you try to update?

Comment: Yes. I just tested it. But I was quite sure because, as I said, the code workes fine if no long field is in the table.

Comment: I don't know if this could possibly have anything to do with the problem but `NumericUpDown.Value` is a Decimal.

Comment: @Mary: Yes, i know. But a .NET decimal consists of [16 Bytes/128bit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/numeric-data-types). This should be enough to hold an 8 Byte/64bit number. Another argument is: Meanwhile I hade exactly the same problem with another control, a modified TextBox. I think, the issue is, the 64bit Long is [quite new in Access](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-the-large-number-data-type-5b623f6e-641d-4e97-8bdf-b77bae076f70).